# Bash script execution after login success does not trigger

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sshpass

I can successfully login from local to a remote server using the bash script. When the login is successful, after a one-line execution, the script does not run to execute other lines. what am I to do to make it execute the script to the end?

```
#! /bin/bash
    sshpass -p 'remotepassword' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    ls -l /var/
    sudo mkdir /var/mydirectories
```

Comment: First I would use key exchange instead of sshpass to avoid having root password written in a script, but that's just me. To answer your question, you should use the switch -f with your ssh.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, could you please, provide a snippet to do as you outlined?

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks. @AndreGelinas

Comment: If your talking about the key exchange, there are several how-to on the net like this one : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work better than my last answer

```
    sshpass -p 'remotepass' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  << EOF
        ls -l /tmp/
        mkdir /tmp/mydirectories
        uname -a
        w
EOF
```

Comment: Your snippets worked perfectly! Is there a way to make it write per line so as to make it readable when writing?